# Different result when adding same attributes to asp control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I have this method that should run on TextChanged of a text box:

```
void CheckIn_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkIn.Text += "It Worked!";
}
```

In the aspx file I have this control:

```
<asp:textbox runat="server" id="checkIn" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoPostBack="true" TextChanged="CheckIn_TextChanged"></asp:textbox>
```

All the attributes work as they should except the `TextChanged`?

But if I remove this from the control and set it in the codebehind on page_load like so: `checkIn.TextChanged = CheckIn_TextChanged;` it does work?!

So my question is this why does it work when setting in codefile behind but not assigning the attribute to the control in the aspx file? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: try checkIn.TextChanged += CheckIn_TextChanged;

Comment: Sorry that is what im currently doing just added in edit, my question is why does this work but not when adding in the aspx file?

Comment: did you also remove the autoPostBack?

Comment: Does auto postback not need to be there for the text box change to take affect?

Comment: yes of course i thought you removed it too. The only thing i think about maybe you assign the event of text change only on IsPostBack=false

Comment: What im ultimately trying to do is get this to work with nothing in code behind other that the event handler.

Comment: I don't see any problem add this only on the client side. don't forget that the control will trigger the event on blur

Answer (score 1):

Event name should be **[OnTextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.ontextchanged.aspx)**. *(Not TextChanged)*

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="checkIn" 
    ClientIDMode="Static" 
    AutoPostBack="true" 
    OnTextChanged="CheckIn_TextChanged">
</asp:TextBox>
```